# mmap length is greater than file size: memory mapping in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, memory-mapping

I am loading a word2vec trained model and trying to memory map using numpy memory mapping.I can successfully make a **.dat** file using numpy memmap But i could not load it in read mode using same memmap function and getting error **mmap length is greater than file size**.(I am getting error in last line of code, see my code snippet). I searched online and read the documentation of **numpy.memmap** function.[Here is the link for documentation of numpy memmap](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) .I found that there is limitation of file size that we can load using above fuction. I will quote form the doc(correct me if i understood wrong).

> Memory-mapped arrays use the Python memory-map object which (prior to Python 2.5) does not allow files to be larger than a certain size depending on the platform. This size is always < 2GB even on 64-bit systems.

My model has size 4 gb.What are the other memory mapping alternatives if file size is more than 2GB? 
Below is the snippet of my code:

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
wv = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(
    "data/trained_model.bin.gz",
    binary=True)
fp = np.memmap("data/embed.dat", dtype=np.double, mode='w+',shape=wv.syn0norm.shape)
fp[:] = wv.syn0norm[:]
with open("data/embed.vocab", "w") as f:
    for _, w in sorted((voc.index, word) for word, voc in wv.vocab.items()):
        print(w, file=f)
del fp, wv

W = np.memmap("data/embed.dat", dtype=np.double, mode="r", shape=(3000000, 300))
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2.5 or older?

Comment: I think that this is likely wrong: `shape=(3000000, 300)`. Note that the call to `np.memmap` on line 5 does work for the same file, using a different `shape`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck i am using Python 3.5.

Comment: @RafG yes i was getting error because of the wrong shape. Now instead of   shape=(3000000, 300) i am using the value **wv.syn0norm.shape**.
and now its working fine.

Comment: what is the best way to initialize shape ?  using wv.syn0norm.shape or with anyvalue?
For my example **wv.syn0norm.shape=485369** and if i use a value greater or less than the above value then i am getting error.